# Use WordPress loop in Sencha touch application i.e parse PHP in JS file

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, sencha-touch

I would like to create a WP loop inside my Sencha Touch application, is this possible?

Any suggestions on a better method of getting posts in to Sencha Touch app?

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest writing a one-off php script that goes through your WP entries and generates a JSON feed that you can use in a data store inside your Sencha app. This is the cleanest and most maintainable way to accomplish what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks, sounds like the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

To make your life easier you can also start by getting this plugin:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-api/

Does exactly what it says it does, turns your WordPress content into json